# Cannot import name 'API' from 'flask_restful'

Tags: python, api, rest, flask

[image: Error]

I am trying to install Flask but I am facing this error. I researched this error on Google but did not find anything specific. How can this be solved?

Comment: The question is not full specify, and it is not programming problem

Comment: It's `Api` not `API`..